# Take photo w/ camera intent and display in imageView or textView?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

I have a question about how to take an image using the camera intent (or camera API) and then bring the image into an imageView for me to display in my application. This is what I have so far.

I setup a button

```
Button btnPicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_picture);
    btnPicture.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I setup a Camera method

```
private void Camera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_CODE);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And this is where I am lost. I am trying to process the image that I took.

```
    private void processImage(Intent intent) {
    setContentView(R.layout.imagelayout);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    cameraBitmap = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
}
```

My intent is to display the image that you took inside image_view. I am not receiving an error, nothing happens. When I take the picture, I am asked to either take another picture or after I use the device back button the application force closes. It seems that I am taken out of my application completely, and returning is a big issue. Any suggestions? What am I missing?

O yea, and here is my onActivityResult

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(TAKE_PICTURE_CODE == requestCode) {

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras.containsKey("data")) {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
            if (image != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "image != null");
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fail to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to put the image in getExtras, and then store it to a ByteArray. Was another thing I was trying to do. Not sure how it all comes together.

Comment: Post you code for `onActivityResult()`..

Comment: Here's a nice project that handles much of the complexity: https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android.  No need for `onActivityResult(..)`, and concise `onRequestPermissionsResult(..)` implementation.  In an SO ocean of [100+ lines] answers to this question, Big thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43707269/2162226

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method which i found to be easy and helpful is this:

**MainActivity**

```
private static String root = null;
private static String imageFolderPath = null;        
private String imageName = null;
private static Uri fileUri = null;
private static final int CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST=1;

public void captureImage(View view) {

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capturedImageview);

             // fetching the root directory
     root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
     + "/Your_Folder";

     // Creating folders for Image
     imageFolderPath = root + "/saved_images";
     File imagesFolder = new File(imageFolderPath);
     imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    // Generating file name
    imageName = "test.png";

    // Creating image here

    File image = new File(imageFolderPath, imageName);

    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

    imageView.setTag(imageFolderPath + File.separator + imageName);

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
            CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}
```

and then in your activity **onActivityResult** method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST:

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Setting image image icon on the imageview

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this
                    .findViewById(R.id.capturedImageview);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            break;

        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

**GetImageThumbnail.java**

```
public class GetImageThumbnail {

private static int getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(double ratio) {
    int k = Integer.highestOneBit((int) Math.floor(ratio));
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return k;
}

public Bitmap getThumbnail(Uri uri, Context context)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    onlyBoundsOptions.inDither = true;// optional
    onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// optional
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
    input.close();
    if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1)
            || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight
            : onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;

    double ratio = (originalSize > 400) ? (originalSize / 350) : 1.0;

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
    bitmapOptions.inDither = true;// optional
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// optional
    input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
    input.close();
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

and then on the **ImageView onclick** method will be like this:

```
public void showFullImage(View view) {
    String path = (String) view.getTag();

    if (path != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
        intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, your example is extensive but has helped. I am facing force closes though. When I get rid of the onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds line that seems to fix the issue but things still aren't working the way I'd like. I'll keep meddling around. But you've helped me progress, thanks!

Comment: This works. Consider making getThumbnail() static, you don't need an instance of its class to use it.

Answer (score 3):

To take photo correctly you should store it in temp file, because data in result intent can be null:

```
final Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
pickIntent.setType("image/*");
pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
final String pickTitle = activity.getString(R.string.choose_image);
final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle);
if (AvailabilityUtils.isExternalStorageReady()) {
    final Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final Uri fileUri = getCameraTempFileUri(activity, true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
    new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent });
}

activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then get photo from Uri:

```
if (requestCode == ProfileDataView.REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            final Uri dataUri = data == null ? getCameraTempFileUri(context,
                false) : data.getData();
                final ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver()
                    .openFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r");
                final FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
        }
```

Comment: 10x, but you should post also `getCameraTempFileUri()`.