# How to resolve OutOfMemoryError on Bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

I want to set an image in `ImageView`, I am retrieving the image path in my first activity and I am passing it via `Intent` as a String to second activity. In the second activity I set the path to an `ImageView`. It's working properly, and I need to upload that picture to a server. So I decoded the path to a bitmap. It throws an `OutOfMemoryError`. How to resolve this issue?

And when I use front camera, there is no issues. Image is uploaded successfully. The problem is with the images taken by front camera of the device. What is the solution for this problem? Can anyone help?

Here is the code to convert the image path to a string and passing it via `Intent`:

```
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
              Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
              photoPath = uri.toString();

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();

            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageUploadActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ImagePath", photoPath);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Method invoked"+photoPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Receiving Intent in Second Activity:

```
 Intent camIntent = getIntent();
 camPicPath = camIntent.getExtras().getString("ImagePath");
 imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(camPicPath));
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "PATHe"+camPicPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 bitmap = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(camPicPath));
```

Method to Upload the file:

```
 class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://11.10.11.15/test/upload.php");

            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();


          /* entity.addPart("uploaded_file", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    "myImage.jpg"));*/

            // String newFilename= filename.concat("file");
            // newFilename=filename+newFilename;

            entity.addPart("uploaded_file", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    filename));
          //  Log.e(TAG, "Method invoked");
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String aux = "";

            while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(aux);
            }

            String sResponse = builder.toString();


            return sResponse;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception Message 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: you have to compress the image.

Comment: visit [Android Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
Bitmap bm = ShrinkBitmap(imagefile, 300, 300);
   image.setImageBitmap(bm);

Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String file, int width, int height) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
    int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight / (float) height);
    int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / (float) width);
    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {
          if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
          } else {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
          }
    }
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Or use `inSampleSize` when setting the image bitmap like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add below property to application tag of manifiest file for high memory.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```