# Take capture using camera, display in imageview and save to pictures

Tags: android

i am trying for month to make simple camera capture with no success. This app i am developing was working great few months ago, but since i update android to version 7 the app stop working correct. I want to click a button, activate the camera (build in not api) after capture to display the image in imageview (in high quality) and save the image to the pictures folder. after that to send the image to server. In the existing version of my app, i was capture the image, display the saved image in the imageview and send to server via json. Now the activity results is null and the imageview is empty :-( Please HELP

Old code that work great for a while

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cancel_btn:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.camera_btn:
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri u = data.getData();
        Log.d("u", String.valueOf(u));
        theImageUriStr = String.valueOf(u);
        Log.d("theImageUriStr", String.valueOf(theImageUriStr));
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
        ALBUM_ART_URI = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(theImageUriStr));
        Picasso.with(AddNewDish.this).load(ALBUM_ART_URI).into(mImageView);
    }
    else{
        Log.d("mmmm", String.valueOf(resultCode));
    }
}
```

The result i am getting from Log.d u and theImageUriStr is null

Comment: Do you check user for permission to use the camera?

Comment: yes. also check for read / write external storage

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "Now the activity results is null" means. Also, please provide a [mcve], which would include the code that calls `startActivityForResult()` for `CAMERA_REQUEST`. For example, if you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, `data.getData()` is *supposed* to be `null`.

Comment: CommonsWare  you have an idea how to fix this null issue please? yes i am using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Answer (score 8):

For 2017,

the only realistic approach to camera in Android is the revolutionary library

## https://github.com/gogopop/CameraKit-Android

It has changed everything in Android development -

there is no other realistic approach possible.

Google (actually their Japan office) finally took it upon themselves to write something that makes android camera into actual software.  That was: https://github.com/google/cameraview . That was a miracle library which took camera difficulty from 10 to 5.

The flurgle library https://github.com/gogopop/CameraKit-Android is the first out of the gate to finally resolve all problems and make the camera work like normal software. Difficulty is now 1.

Do this to put a live camera in your app

```
<com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Do this to take photos

```
cameraView.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) {
   super.onPictureTaken(picture);
   Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);
   save the image...
  });
```

It's all over. That's it.

## Ten years of *living hell* with Android camera is finally finished.

Comment: In an SO ocean of [100+ lines] answers to this question, this by far looks the best. Big Thanks for sharing here

Comment: @GeneBo - right.  And fortunately in the two years since then it has improved more!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the in-built camera application to take the picture and return the image back to your app, follow these steps:

1. Add this to your manifest:`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
       android:required="true" />`
2. Use this function in your activity to invoke the camera:

   `private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
   Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                 startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
       }
   }`
3. Use this function to handle the image received from camera:

   `@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
           //mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
       }
   }`

Cheers!